# how to fix the order in which my program outfiles?

Tags: perl

So i have a program that pulls in sorted data (increasing in descending order) based on two columns and outfiles this data into a text file that plugs the data into a text file. The problem i am running into is that it doesnt produce an output in the same order as it was read into the program.

Here is a sample of the data set:

```
2, 1, 20, 1, 10, 28.5714285, 0, 
2, 1, 72, 3, 7, 20, 0, 
2, 2, 20, 3, 19, 52.7777777, 0, 
5, 1, 66, 3, 199, 21.1927582, 0, 
5, 1, 5, 2, 153, 16.2939297, 0,
```

Here is a sample of an out of order output:

```
fci
u
csno=51 svgrp=0 antfc= 2
cdmanbr_list1.ncs_c[1]= 51
cdmanbr_list1.nghbrantf[1]= 1
cdmanbr_list1.pilot_pn[1]=
cdmanbr_list1.pgn_c[1]= 0
u
u
csno=66 svgrp=0 antfc= 2
cdmanbr_list1.ncs_c[1]= 66
cdmanbr_list1.nghbrantf[1]= 1
cdmanbr_list1.pilot_pn[1]=
cdmanbr_list1.pgn_c[1]= 0
u
u
csno=51 svgrp=0 antfc= 3
cdmanbr_list1.ncs_c[1]= 51
cdmanbr_list1.nghbrantf[1]= 1
cdmanbr_list1.pilot_pn[1]=
cdmanbr_list1.pgn_c[1]= 0
u
```

Notice how the value of the third "csno" (51) is less than the second "csno" value (66). And even though there are 2 "csno" of equal value, the "antfc" values are different. The desired output is the following:

```
fci
u
csno=51 svgrp=0 antfc= 2
cdmanbr_list1.ncs_c[1]= 51
cdmanbr_list1.nghbrantf[1]= 1
cdmanbr_list1.pilot_pn[1]=
cdmanbr_list1.pgn_c[1]= 0
u
u
csno=51 svgrp=0 antfc= 3
cdmanbr_list1.ncs_c[1]= 51
cdmanbr_list1.nghbrantf[1]= 1
cdmanbr_list1.pilot_pn[1]=
cdmanbr_list1.pgn_c[1]= 0
u
u
csno=66 svgrp=0 antfc= 2
cdmanbr_list1.ncs_c[1]= 66
cdmanbr_list1.nghbrantf[1]= 1
cdmanbr_list1.pilot_pn[1]=
cdmanbr_list1.pgn_c[1]= 0
u
```

Here is a copy of the program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use POSIX qw(strftime);

( $sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year, $wday, $yday, $isdst ) =
  localtime(time);

my $bdate = sprintf( "%02d%02d%02d", $mon + 1, $mday - 7, $year - 100 );
my $edate = sprintf( "%02d%02d%02d", $mon + 1, $mday - 1, $year - 100 );

my $newresult = "/home/user/newresults/recommended_$bdate-$edate.csv";
my $script    = "/home/user/update_scripts/update_$bdate-$edate.txt";

my $h;
my $k;
my $n;
my $fh = undef;
open( $fh,  '<', $newresult ) or die $!;
open( $fsh, '>', $script )    or die $!;
print $fsh "fci\n";
while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
    next if $. < 2;
    chomp $line;
    my @array = split( /\,/, $line );
    my $key = "csno=$array[0] svgrp=0 antfc=$array[1]";
    push( @{ $h->{$key} }, $array[6] );
    push( @{ $k->{$key} }, $array[2] );
    push( @{ $n->{$key} }, $array[3] );
} ## end while ( my $line = <$fh> )

foreach my $key ( keys %{$h} ) {
    print $fsh "u\n";
    print $fsh "$key\n";
    if ( @{ $h->{$key} } <= 12 ) {
        for ( my $i = 1 ; $i <= @{ $h->{$key} } ; $i++ ) {
            my $m = $i - 1;
            print $fsh "cdmanbr_list1.ncs_c[$i]=${$k->{$key}}[$m]\n";
            print $fsh "cdmanbr_list1.nghbrantf[$i]=${$n->{$key}}[$m]\n";
            print $fsh "cdmanbr_list1.pilot_pn[$i]=\n";
            print $fsh "cdmanbr_list1.pgn_c[$i]=${$h->{$key}}[$m]\n";
        } ## end for ( my $i = 1 ; $i <=...)
        for ( my $i = @{ $h->{$key} } + 1 ; $i < 13 ; $i++ ) {
            my $m = $i - 1;
            print $fsh "cdmanbr_list1.ncs_c[$i]=\n";
            print $fsh "cdmanbr_list1.nghbrantf[$i]=\n";
            print $fsh "cdmanbr_list1.pilot_pn[$i]=\n";
            print $fsh "cdmanbr_list1.pgn_c[$i]=\n";
        } ## end for ( my $i = @{ $h->{$key...}})
    } ## end if ( @{ $h->{$key} } <=...)
    print $fsh "u\n";
} ## end foreach my $key ( keys %{$h...})
```

Comment: *"and outfiles this data into a text file that plugs the data into a text file"* I have never heard of *outfiling*, and how does this text file that you "outfile" plug the data into another text file?

Comment: Please *always* `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of every Perl program you write, especially before publishing it and asking for help. There is little point in typing all those `my` declarations without `use strict`

Answer (score 0):

The source of your problem is that in

```
foreach my $key (keys%{$h}){
```

You are expecting that the keys of the hash will be in some pre-defined order.  That's not how hashes work.

2 reasonable solutions are:

- (optimize for effort) If you know the input file is sorted as you desire, push `$key` into an array as you are building `%$h` and interrate over it instead.  i.e.

  `foreach my $key (@keyorder) {`
- (optimize for memory) take the (apparently) unsorted list of keys and sort them:

  `foreach my $key (sort { ### comparison here ### } keys %{$h}) {`

Where your comparison might take the form of: `((split $a, /=/)[1] <=> (split $b, /=/)[1]) || ((split $a, /=/)[-1] <=> (split $b, /=/)[-1])` depending on the details of your sorting requirements.

---

While C style for loops have their place in Perl, your inner loops could benefit from some idiomatic Perl.

```
for my $i ( 1 .. @{$h->{key}} ) {
  #stuff
}
for my $i ( @{$h->{key}}+1 .. 12 ) {
  #other stuff
}
```

Comment: What would it look like to push the string `$key` into an array as i am building `%$h` look like? Like how can this be done? i appreciate the help!

Comment: @m.lochhead You're already doing 3 more complicated pushes in the build process, so I'd imagined you'd come up with `push @keyorder $key;` on your own....

Comment: Oh ok i didnt know if there was a specific way i should approach this or not. thank you very much!